# Drupal custom login/registration in front end

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, authentication, frontend

I'm developing a website using Drupal 6. I'm using my own theme and it's all working perfectly. Now i need to create a custom login/registration form in my website using my custom theme. I have tried a lot of ways, but everything redirects to my admin theme, the same thing happens with login errors.

How can i fix these problems and do a login/registration forms using my front end theme?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Customizing and Overriding User Login page, Register, and Password Reset in Drupal 6](http://drupal.org/node/350634).